# Why does my Seaborn Pairplot take forever to plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a `Pandas DataFrame` made up of `274,170 rows and 15 columns`. They are all `numerical columns`. I am interested in using the `Seaborn's Pairplot` to see their `distribution and correlation`. Out of the 15 columns, I would like to see this for 9 columns instead.

Here is my attempt:

```py
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
    g = sns.pairplot(df, 
                     palette="husl",
                     vars=["age", "amount", "dir", "type",
                           "reg", "per", "reason",
                           "deal", "policy", "request"])
```

This takes forever! Please what is the issue. What can I do to use the `Seaborn Pairplot` as this is the type of `Data visualization` I am looking forward to in order to understand my data properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A seaborn pairplot is quite heavy on resources, especially with lots of columns and rows. With a large number of rows I suggest to plot a fraction of the data(frame) to get a pretty good indication of the data.

```
n = 274_170
frac = 0.10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n, 10),
                  columns = ["age", "amount", "dir", "type", "reg", "per", "reason", "deal", "policy", "request"])
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
sns.pairplot(df.sample(frac=frac), palette="husl", vars=["age", "amount", "dir", "type", "reg", "per", "reason", "deal", "policy", "request"])
plt.show()
```